Parsing error in my graph stating that content is not allowed in prolog
I just inserted the following graph:
@prefix : <http://buchmann.ro#>.
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.

:moviesInfo
{
#some movie directors
:JamesCameron   :directorOf :Avatar,:Terminator;
                :hasName "James Cameron".
:JohnMcT            :directorOf :Predator, :DieHard;
                    :hasName "John McTiernan";
                    :birthInfo  [   :birthDate "1951-01-08"^^xsd:date;
                :birthPlace  :USA].
:McG        :directorOf  _:somemovie;
    :hasName "Joseph McGinty";
    :hasNickname "McG".
:TimBurton  :directorOf :Batman;
    :hasName "Tim Burton";
    :birthPlace :USA.
 #some movie actors
:SamWorth   :hasName "Sam Worthington";
:playedIn _:somemovie;
:playedTheRole [:asCharacter :JakeSully;
                    :inMovie :Avatar].
:Arnold         :playedIn :Terminator,:Predator;
        :wasGovernorOf :California;
            :hasName "Arnold Schwarzenegger";
                    :birthInfo [:birthDate "1947-07-10"^^xsd:date;
                            :birthPlace  :Austria].
:LindaH         :hasName "Linda Hamilton";
:playedTheRole [:asCharacter :SarahConnor;
:inMovie :Terminator].
:JackNicholson  :playedIn :Batman;
:hasName "Jack Nicholson".

#this guy is both actor and director
:ShBlack        :playedIn :Predator;
    :hasName "Shane Black";
    :directorOf :KKBB.





  #some movies
 :Batman        :hasTitle "Batman".
 :Terminator    :hasTitle "Terminator";
            :hasBudget 6400000 .
  :Avatar       :hasTitle "Avatar";
    :hasBudget 237000000 .
 :DieHard       :hasTitle "Die Hard".
 :Predator      :hasTitle "Predator";
            :hasBudget 18000000 .
 :KKBB      :hasTitle "Kiss Kiss Bang Bang";
    :hasBudget 15000000 .
 _:somemovie    :hasBudget 200000000 .

 #some movie characters
:JakeSully      :hasName "Jake Sully".
:SarahConnor    :hasName "Sarah Connor".
}

:geoInfo
{
    #some countries/states
 :California        :partOf     :USA;
 :hasName "California"@en, "Californie"@fr.
   :Austria         :hasName "Austria"@en, "Autriche"@fr.
   :USA     :hasName "United States of America"@en, "Etats Unis d'Amerique"@fr.
 }

My problem is that I tried to introduced many times into the GraphDB, also tried to parse differenty, but I got the same error:

RDF Parse Error: Content is not allowed in prolog. [line 1, column 1]

I am trying to learn RDF again, so I am very beginner, but trying my best. Thank you!

I can upload your file into GraphDB without getting any errors. How do you try to insert it?

That looks like TriG syntax - so how do you load this? If it's a file, did you use .trig as file extension? If yes, what exactly are you doing to load the data?

It worked. This is how a humble starts looks like. :)))))
